# Create DocuSign user without sending activation email using eSign SDK?

Tags: docusignapi, electronic-signature

I am using DocuSign eSign SDK V3.1.1 to create user in DocuSign without sending any activation email to user. I want password and forgotten password information to be set from API itself so that after this call user can immediately start using their account. I am using below code for this purpose:

```
UserInformation userInformation = new UserInformation()
{
    UserName = data["UserName"], 
    Email = data["UserEmail"], 
    SendActivationEmail = "false",
    Password = "123456",
    ForgottenPasswordInfo = new ForgottenPasswordInformation()
    {
        ForgottenPasswordQuestion1 = "What is the name of your first pet?",
        ForgottenPasswordAnswer1 = "Pogo"
    },
    PermissionProfileId = "XXXXX"

};

List<UserInformation> usersInfo = new List<UserInformation>() { userInformation };

NewUsersDefinition newUsersDefinition = new NewUsersDefinition()
{
    NewUsers = usersInfo
};

var result = usersApi.Create(accountId, newUsersDefinition);
```

However, the ctivation email is still sent to user and password and forgotten password is not set from the API. Am I missing something in above request? Or do I need to set any other parameter to achieve the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silent Activation through the eSignature API is only available on some account types, and is no longer generally available. The supported way to do this is now through the Organization API, as documented here: https://developers.docusign.com/orgadmin-api/code-examples/add-user

If you don't currently have an Organization with a Claimed Domain, you'll want to reach out to your Account Manager or the Sales team to have the Organization module added to your account. [DocuSign Support](https://support.docusign.com/) can enable that on a Demo/Sandbox account, open a Support case and provide your demo account ID.

Comment: Hi Drew, while creating user using "auto_activate_memberships": true, attribute it is showing response as unauthenticated user. it works without this attribute and creates the user. but I need to make the user active while creating, how this can be done?

Comment: Do you have a claimed domain, and is the user you're attempting to activate under that domain?